# create json using json_encode in php

Tags: php

i have the following code, which does some tasks, and returns dates:

```
<?php
        if (valid value]):
            echo "some data";
            print format_date() . '-';
            if (second test) print format_date(); // prints 01/09/2020
            else print format_date(); // prints 10/09/2020
            echo "valid until";
                print format_date(...); // prints 14/09/2020
            endif;
```

desired json:

```
[
{status: 'some data', dates: { from: '01/09/2020', to: '10/09/2020'}, til: {label: 'valid until', date: 'Fri 14/09/2020'}}
]
```

whatever i tried, gets me to create a json array, while i need the above structure, how should i alter the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but this is how you can encode an array to JSON.

```
<?php
$myArray = [];
if(1 == 1) $myArray["test"] = "1 is equal to 1";
if(1 !== 2) $myArray["test2"] = "1 is not equal 2";
print_r(json_encode($myArray, true));
```

Output: `{"test":"1 is equal to 1","test2":"1 is not equal 2"}`

The array is defined at the beginning and is then filled.
At the end it is encoded with json_encode and output.

This should be the code what you need:

```
<?php

$myArray = []; # This array is filled below and encoded to json at the end

if(1 == 1) { # Your if-statement
    $myArray["status"] = 'some data';
    $dates = []; # This array is the "dates" array
    $dates["from"] = "Date 1";
    if(1 == 2){ # Your second if-statement
        $dates["from"] = "Date 2";
    }else {
        $dates["to"] = "Date 3";
    }
    $myArray["dates"] = $dates; # Add the "dates" array to your main array
    $myArray["til"] = [
        "label" => "valid until",
        "date" => "Date 4",
    ];
}

$json = json_encode($myArray, true); # Parse your array to json
print_r($json);
```